# Does Salesforce have alternative to "lightning out" for publishing lwc components on public force.com site?

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, force.com-sites

When we use visualforce + $Lightning.use script it takes about 9 seconds to display components. Which is huge delay. Is that the only way that we can use lwc on public force.com site/community?